# Parameters with braces in python

Tags: python, parameters, python-3.x, curly-braces

If you look at the following line of python code:

```
bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add({"object":bpy.data.objects[2]})
```

you see that in the parameters there is something enclosed in braces.  Can anyone tell me what the braces are for (generically anyway)?  I haven't really seen this type of syntax in python and I can't find any documentation on it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> Dictionaries can be created by placing a comma-separated list of key: value pairs **within braces**, for example: `{'jack': 4098, 'sjoerd': 4127}` or `{4098: 'jack', 4127: 'sjoerd'}`, or by the `dict` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The braces create a dictionary.  `particle_system_add` seems to be accepting a dictionary as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

It's just a dictionary with a single key/value pair of "object" as the key and whatever bpy.data.objects[2] evaluates to as the value.